# remove duplicate pairs from the list in column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I would like to remove duplicate pairs from the list in column while mainting the order:

for example the input is :

```
   cola.   colb
     1.  [sitea,siteb,sitea,siteb;sitec,sited,sitec,sited]
```

the expected output is the unique elements before each ';' symbol

```
  cola.   colb
     1.  [sitea,siteb;sitec,sited]
```

I tried splitting the column based on the ; symbol and the create a set for the list but it didn't work.

```
df['test'] = df.e2etrail.str.split(';').map(lambda x : ','.join(sorted(set(x),key=x.index)))
```

I also tried the following

```
df['test'] = df['e2etrail'].apply(lambda x: list(pd.unique(x)))
```

Any idea on how to make it work

Comment: is the content in colb a list of strings or just one string? if it is a list of strings,is it safe to assume then that ```;``` is also a string and that comma is the only delimiter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually I did it by converting the list into series, dropped the duplicates and joined the series again as following :

```
        df['e2etrails']=df['e2etrails'].str.split(';')
        df['e2etrails']=df['e2etrails'].apply(lambda row :';'.join(pd.Series(row).str.split(',').map(lambda x : ','.join(sorted(set(x),key=x.index)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `[]` by strip and then split by `,` or `;` first and then use your solution:

```
print (df.e2etrail.str.strip('[]').str.split('[;,]'))
dtype: object
0    [sitea, siteb, sitea, siteb, sitec, sited, sit...
Name: e2etrail, dtype: object
```

---

```
f = lambda x : ','.join(sorted(set(x),key=x.index))
df['test'] = df.e2etrail.str.strip('[]').str.split('[;,]').map(f)
print (df)
   cola.                                           e2etrail  \
0    1.0  [sitea,siteb,sitea,siteb;sitec,sited,sitec,sited]   

                      test  
0  sitea,siteb,sitec,sited
```

If need output list:

```
f = lambda x : sorted(set(x),key=x.index)
df['test'] = df.e2etrail.str.strip('[]').str.split('[;,]').map(f)
print (df)
   cola.                                           e2etrail  \
0    1.0  [sitea,siteb,sitea,siteb;sitec,sited,sitec,sited]   

                           test  
0  [sitea, siteb, sitec, sited]
```

Comment: What if I want to preserve the (;) delimiter between each two pairs so the expected outcome should be something like [sitea,siteb;sitec,sited]

Comment: @Fighter So you need list like `[sitea, siteb, sitec, sited]`? Then is not possible delimiter `;`. Or need strings like `sitea,siteb;sitec,sited`?

Comment: if the delimiter can't be added unless they are strings, I would accept that. I proposed an answer but I don't think it is the best approach to tackle this issue